# How to add script tag in the html file after where jquery.js is included but before ending body tag using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
       ...
       <script src="jquery.js"></script>
       // script tag should be added here
    </body>
</html>
```

i know tag can be added with appendChild() method but i am not sure that it will add new script tag where i want. any suggestion??

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: If you are adding a script tag dynamically with appendChild then it doesn't mather where you put it...

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it where you want.

```
function add( url ) {
    var elem = document.createElement( 'script' );
    elem.setAttribute( 'src', url );
    document.body.appendChild( elem );
}
```

It should work fine.